# JavaScript make captcha text not copyable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, captcha

I am using client side captcha for basic spam protection, and my created script generates random numbers. I give background ('noisy')  image to the input where I display my generated numbers  and I have used:

```
$('#nrx_txtCaptcha').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
          return false;
   });
```

to disable right click but when highlight captcha textfiedd's  numbers you can copy that via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. So how to make it not copyable? Or there is a way I can make it not "highlighable" ?

Comment: How should clientside captchas help to protect against spam? A bot will not use javascript, it sends just an HTTP request to your server (with a spoofed captcha-is-correct parameter)

Comment: Thanks . But as I mentioned BASIC spam protection. Can you suggest a solution to my problem ?

Comment: Use a canvas element to display the text in an image. But no, you can't make text unextractable from the DOM - not allowing to select&copy is only a curtailing of the user, it is not suitable for captchas. Your approach makes automated spamming easier than human contributions.

Comment: But would that work in IE7,FF and not that much newer versions  ofbrowsers ?

Comment: No. But that doesn't matter, you would just need to disable JavaScript to not see any captchas…

Comment: this not a solution the problem

Comment: If the CAPTCHA is stored as text in the HTML, then it is not a CAPTCHA. To be one, it must be able to "Tell Computers and Humans Apart". Any computer can parse plaintext.

Comment: Thank you people for your thoughts and downvotes but the "CAPTHCA"  is for "dumb users"  the server side will take care of all the nasty stuff

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an onmouseup to the element where the captcha is in, and check if something is selected with `document.selection()` after that. But I VERY MUCH agree with (I don't care if that's good English - you get my point) Bergi.

Comment: There is a `select` event, use that. `onmouseup` does not really help.

Comment: Only if you put the captcha in an input or textarea element, which not necessarily is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I find I needed to my this problem .

```
    // Disable paste to input field
  jQuery('#nrx_txtInput').bind("paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }); 
       //  Disable copy from captcha field
 jQuery('#nrx_txtCaptcha').bind("copy",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```